# max value for a year

Tags: r, max

Hi i am new to r and I have to solve this question below

consider that i have a data below for three years (36months)

```
psl(Pascal)    tos(K)        ua(m/s)       va(m/s)
100828.2422 300.6350403 -2.908552885    -5.041597843
100865.375  300.6374512 -1.974732399    -3.884183884
100781.0156 301.3094177 -1.220992327    -2.782843351
100842.8359 302.0706787 -0.3339158      -2.049038887
100618.3516 303.1063843 0.983095765      0.187034369
100679.1641 302.6870117 2.236735344      3.573194027
100818.4219 302.1689758 1.754112124      2.603042126
100788.2266 302.3732605 -0.338575393    2.111710548
100712.1406 302.4180908 -1.487656116    1.750846267
100731.6406 302.4753723 -0.984614015    1.460931182
100643.4844 302.334198  0.101298548     0.029232573
100622.4297 302.1279297 -2.22670269     -0.482721329
100709.9453 301.0938721 -3.413815022    -2.25238204
100748.8516 300.9854736 -3.758933067    -1.831826091
100696.9063 301.7830505 -3.490354538    -1.195819378
100746.9063 302.3372192 -1.486986399    0.289745539
100676.6875 302.3781433 1.985690475     2.395581245
100720.4063 302.1488037 2.89744854       2.710779667
100734.3516 301.815155  3.502389193     3.37501812
100760.0078 301.9842834 1.93155086       3.437204123
100837.7109 302.2229614 3.258229494      2.887587547
100803.9375 302.8745422 2.309668064      0.393238485
100627.1563 302.821106  -0.111538976    -1.064256191
100740.8047 302.0934143 -1.853200674    -3.353952885
100871.6953 301.3536682 -3.842114687    -4.386196136
100797.3203 301.2049255 -4.432024479    -4.506450653
100762.2344 301.9281921 -3.15829277     -2.483273268
100761.7734 302.6669312 -0.989763916    -0.868626654
100717.8828 303.0666809 2.604245424     1.605101585
100726.2656 302.9170837 2.931357622    2.646541834
100754.5156 302.7220459 2.797704458    3.948915482
100771.8438 302.7012939 1.819163561    3.766605854
100741.5859 302.6376038 3.746546745    3.388780594
100825.75   302.8607178 2.811676979    0.938653767
100792.7031 302.8861694 0.876988828     -1.316085815
100783.8438 302.0106506 -0.735642731    -3.267586231
```

what i want is to find maximum value for data "tos(K)" for every 12months.
the result shown should be

```
    tos(K)
[1]303.1063843
[2]302.8745422
[3]303.0666809
```

consider that the first data be Jan 1st year and last data be the Dis 3rd year.

how can I plot block maxima afterwards?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

this is what i've tried.. first add year column manually and delete the 1st, 3rd and 4th column as i want only tos(K) dataset. i change tos(K) into temperature.

```
year    temperature
2005    300.6350403
2005    300.6374512
2005    301.3094177
2005    302.0706787
2005    303.1063843
2005    302.6870117
2005    302.1689758
2005    302.3732605
2005    302.4180908
2005    302.4753723
2005    302.334198
2005    302.1279297
2006    301.0938721
2006    300.9854736
2006    301.7830505
2006    302.3372192
2006    302.3781433
2006    302.1488037
2006    301.815155
2006    301.9842834
2006    302.2229614
2006    302.8745422
2006    302.821106
2006    302.0934143
2007    301.3536682
2007    301.2049255
2007    301.9281921
2007    302.6669312
2007    303.0666809
2007    302.9170837
2007    302.7220459
2007    302.7012939
2007    302.6376038
2007    302.8607178
2007    302.8861694
2007    302.0106506
```

my coding is as follow:

```
malaysia<-read.table("datamalaysiatry.csv",header=T, sep=",")
aggregate(temperature ~ year , data = malaysia, max)
```

the result shown:

```
 year temperature
1 2016    303.1064
2 2017    302.8745
3 2018    303.0667
```

but as i stated at my comment, i have thousands of dataset. it's really take my time to add the year column manually.

Comment: Do you have a date column? Otherwise you have to manually extract each year of data `max(data[1:12,"tos(K)"]`, `max(data[13:24,"tos(K)"]`, `max(data[25:36,"tos(K)"]`

Comment: i don't have a date column..maybe i can add year column on the left side..by the way this is just an example...my real data consist thousand of data(95 years=1140 months)..

Comment: as an example you can try this and it would add a year column to your dataset. `data$Year = rep(paste("Year",1:95),each=12,95)`. You would probably want to have a numeric value for your year though. Or you could do something similar to @AntoniosK answer `df %>%
  mutate(year = rep(paste("Year",1:95),each=12,95)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%     
  summarise(MaxTos = max(tos.K.)`

Comment: I would definitely spend the time learning how to use the `dplyr` package. I put off learning it for a few years because I thought it was going to be complicated, it's not at all. And it's a HUGE time saver once you get the hang of it

Comment: i'll try to add column to my dataset by using your idea. sound more easy and efficient. i've try dplyr package but looks like i don't understand the function as i always get error... what i have try for now is add year column on the left side manually on excel and use aggregate function..take time to finish all of my dataset..:(

Comment: Let us know what you've tried and what the error is. Maybe via a different question, or post it after your initial question.

Comment: i just post under my initial questions so that it will not make the others confuse

Comment: The update works fine using the `aggregate` function. I meant to show us what you've tried with `dplyr` that had an error so we can work it out.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding...i'll try use the dplyr then post it and hope that all of u can help fix my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a variable/column which defines the year period (12 months).
Then for each year you can get the maximum value of tos(K).

Note that the column names will automatically change because of some characters.

Check my example below:

```
library(dplyr)

#import data
df <- read.table(text = " psl(Pascal)    tos(K)        ua(m/s)       va(m/s)
100828.2422 300.6350403 -2.908552885    -5.041597843
100865.375  300.6374512 -1.974732399    -3.884183884
100781.0156 301.3094177 -1.220992327    -2.782843351
100842.8359 302.0706787 -0.3339158      -2.049038887
100618.3516 303.1063843 0.983095765      0.187034369
100679.1641 302.6870117 2.236735344      3.573194027
100818.4219 302.1689758 1.754112124      2.603042126
100788.2266 302.3732605 -0.338575393    2.111710548
100712.1406 302.4180908 -1.487656116    1.750846267
100731.6406 302.4753723 -0.984614015    1.460931182
100643.4844 302.334198  0.101298548     0.029232573
100622.4297 302.1279297 -2.22670269     -0.482721329
100709.9453 301.0938721 -3.413815022    -2.25238204
100748.8516 300.9854736 -3.758933067    -1.831826091
100696.9063 301.7830505 -3.490354538    -1.195819378
100746.9063 302.3372192 -1.486986399    0.289745539
100676.6875 302.3781433 1.985690475     2.395581245
100720.4063 302.1488037 2.89744854       2.710779667
100734.3516 301.815155  3.502389193     3.37501812
100760.0078 301.9842834 1.93155086       3.437204123
100837.7109 302.2229614 3.258229494      2.887587547
100803.9375 302.8745422 2.309668064      0.393238485
100627.1563 302.821106  -0.111538976    -1.064256191
100740.8047 302.0934143 -1.853200674    -3.353952885
100871.6953 301.3536682 -3.842114687    -4.386196136
100797.3203 301.2049255 -4.432024479    -4.506450653
100762.2344 301.9281921 -3.15829277     -2.483273268
100761.7734 302.6669312 -0.989763916    -0.868626654
100717.8828 303.0666809 2.604245424     1.605101585
100726.2656 302.9170837 2.931357622    2.646541834
100754.5156 302.7220459 2.797704458    3.948915482
100771.8438 302.7012939 1.819163561    3.766605854
100741.5859 302.6376038 3.746546745    3.388780594
100825.75   302.8607178 2.811676979    0.938653767
100792.7031 302.8861694 0.876988828     -1.316085815
100783.8438 302.0106506 -0.735642731    -3.267586231  ",header = TRUE)

df %>%
  mutate(year = c(rep("year1",12), rep("year2",12), rep("year3",12))) %>%  # create -somehow- a variable that shows the time-period (12 months)
  group_by(year) %>%                # group by that variable
  summarise(MaxTos = max(tos.K.))   # find maximum value for each group

#    year   MaxTos
#   (chr)    (dbl)
# 1 year1 303.1064
# 2 year2 302.8745
# 3 year3 303.0667
```

Comment: what does it mean by %>%?

Comment: as i run the last 4 coding in R, i get Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Make sure you have the dplyr package installed.

Comment: dplyr package and function looks so easy and simple. it's proven  from your example,  but as i try it myself, i always end up with error..but, i'll learn and try to use it. really appreciate with your suggestion for a newbie just like me

Comment: dplyr and data.table packages are really useful for those kind of cases. So, if you can "transform" your question into a data wrangling/manipulation problem you can use those packages. Check these : https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf and https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf .

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert to a time series object. Follow AntoniosK's code to create the data frame, df then apply the following code

```
x<-ts(df$tos.K., freq=12)
aggregate(x, FUN=max)
```